# how to uncheck the checkbox on a click of certain event coming from another component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I need your help. I'm trying to uncheck a checkbox on a click of event which is coming from another component/ Outside component emitting event, based on the emitted value, I want to uncheck the checkbox.

You can find below snippet of code, that I tried, but I 'm getting null and not able to uncheck.

```
<mat-menu #childMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
    <span *ngFor="let child of items">
      <!-- Handle branch node menu items -->
      <span *ngIf="child.children && child.children.length > 0">
        <button mat-menu-item color="primary" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu.childMenu">
          <span>{{child.displayName}}</span>
        </button>
        <app-menu-item #menu [items]="child.children"></app-menu-item>
      </span>
      <!-- Handle leaf node menu items -->
      <span *ngIf="!child.children || child.children.length === 0">
        <mat-checkbox style="display: block; margin-left: 5px; padding: 5px;"
             id={{child.key}}
             (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="onSelectMetrics($event, child)">
          <span>{{child.displayName}}</span>
        </mat-checkbox>
      </span>
    </span>
  </mat-menu>
```

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.metricService.metricUnselected
      .subscribe(
        (keyValue) => {
          console.log(`keyValue = ${keyValue}`)
         let element = document.getElementById(keyValue) as HTMLInputElement;
         console.log(element);
         element.checked = false;
        }
      )
  }
```

This is the `sample.json`, which helps me in creating the dynamic drowndown have checkbox as value.
`"displayName": "Select Metrics",
      "children": [
        {
          "displayName": "Cache metrics",
          "children": [
            {
              "displayName": "Read hit(%)",
              "key": "rhit_perc"
            },
            {
              "displayName": "Write hit(%)",
              "key": "whit_perc",
              "labelName": "Cache metrics"
            },`

[image]`

I've subscribed to an event and getting the emitted value. Here in mycase `keyValue`, I want to uncheck the checkbox on the basis of `keyValue`.

Comment: Kindly provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem

Comment: you can simply bind your checkbox with [(ngModel)]="someProperty" , and modify this property on your requirements

Comment: @yanky_cranky, my requirement is based on `keyValue`, I want the <mat-checkbox having id='keyValue'> to be unchecked